# Table width goes beyond the div border

Tags: html, css

I have table within the div. If I view it with IE9 or FF then it is ok. But if I view it within IE8 the table grows beyond the div border. Any ideas?

```
<div>
  <table width="100%" >
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @user sorry i didn't cee that you already gave width as 100%

Comment: @can you post the complete html with data, i think text might be going beyond , try overflow

Comment: Keep scrolling to find the most upvoted answer: `table-layout: fixed`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

found the solution here:

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200704/how_to_prevent_html_tables_from_becoming_too_wide/

> The trick is to use the CSS property `table-layout`. It can take three
>   values: auto, fixed, and inherit. The normal (initial) value is auto,
>   which means that the table width is given by its columns and any
>   borders. In other words, it expands if necessary.
>
> What you want to use is `table-layout:fixed`. Bam! Now the table is as
>   wide as you have specified in the CSS. No more, no less. And to my
>   great surprise this seems to be widely supported by browsers. The only
>   browser of any significance that does not support it is IE/Mac, and
>   the significance of that browser is rapidly approaching zero.
>
> Next is deciding what to do with the content that doesn’t fit in the
>   table anymore. If the table only contains text, word-wrap:break-word
>   (word-wrap is specified in the CSS3 Text Effects Module) will force
>   the browser to break words as necessary to prevent overflow.

Comment: The topic is old, but i will add something to help the future readers. Don't forget to say that  `table-layout: fixed` will force the columns to have the same width. So If you use this trick, you have to force (set) again each column of your table the way you will like.

Comment: The topic is even older, but I will add that I got here looking for a solution where a DIV with the style "display:table" was extending outside its parent DIV. Adding "table-layout: fixed" resolved the issue. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 7):

You could set it inside its own div with `overflow: scroll;` so that it makes a scrollbar when the table expands too much...

Comment: I used overflow-x:auto so I'd get a horizontal scrollbar only when it was too wide. This suits my design perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

Add the style `display:table` to the div tag. This causes the element to act like a table.

Answer (score 2):

Give table width as 100% so that it will occupy div and wont cross it.

Answer (score 2):

As user384080 [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4241119/5136131), `table-layout:fixed` should be added. However, merely having `table-layout` doesn't always fix the problem. Please make sure that you add the `width` attribute as well:

```
<table style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed">
```

Answer (score 0):

check what box-sizing is set by default by the browser.

`box-sizing: content-box`; means:

> The specified width and height apply
>   to the width and height respectively
>   of the content box of the element. The
>   padding and border of the element are
>   drawn outside this area.

`box-sizing: border-box`; means:

> The specified width and height
>   determine the border box of the
>   element. Any padding or border
>   specified on the element is drawn
>   inside the remaining area. The content
>   box is computed by subtracting the
>   padding or border widths of the
>   respective sides from the specified
>   width and height.

it night just be a matter of changing the `box-sizing` value.
there's an article about it here: http://ie8demo.com/BoxSizing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a width set on the div? If so, it will stick to its width, allowing the table to overlap. Try removing the width and it will expand to its container's width. If you want thwe div to fit the table size, you can float it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the first answer, make sure that the container element of the div has `overflow: auto` or `scroll`. The [clearfix hack](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp) is helpful, too.